# Why jms client getting error JMSWMQ0018 error

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

My MQ client application is usually functional, but occasionally I encounter errors like this one:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to the 'PCMQPROD' queue manager using connection mode 'Client' and host name '172.xx.xx.xxx(1415)'. To resolve this issue, please verify that the queue manager is started and that a listener is running if the queue manager is operating in client mode. Refer to the linked exception for more details.
```

I checked the MQ server log file (`AMQERR01.LOG`), but it only shows that the channel ended abnormally without specifying the reason behind it:

```
EXPLANATION:
The attempt to connect to the 'PROD' queue manager failed due to reason code 2059.
ACTION:
Make sure that the queue manager is up and running.

----- amqrmsaa.c : 602 --------------------------------------------------------
04/11/2023 11:41:56 AM - Process(22526.12) User(mqm) Program(runmqlsr)
Host(domainname)
AMQ9999: Channel program ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The 'CHAN1.SVRCONN' channel program ended abnormally.
ACTION:
Check the error files for previous error messages related to the 'CHAN1.SVRCONN' channel program to determine the cause of the failure.
```

Are there any other logs or checks I can perform on the server to determine the root cause of the error? What could be causing the problem?

Comment: On the client side you should  **Refer to the linked exception for more details.** On the queue manager for any AMQ9999 error there should be 1 or more errors above it usually with the same `Process` that show the cause.

Comment: If that snippet of the error log is from the queue manager side of things, it is telling you that the queue manager called 'PROD' is not running. You need to start the queue manager.

Comment: Yes,Logs says queue manager is not running but I m looking Why it stopped running,logs shows nothing.

Comment: What are the error messages in the queue manager error log that precede the one which says "AMQ9542W: Queue manager is ending."  or "AMQ8004I: IBM MQ queue manager 'MQG1' ended." ? Also, are you certain it wasn't manually ended?